# Using JSOUP to print specific rows

Tags: java, web-scraping, html-table, jsoup, row

I would like to extract the text from specific row in a given table, for example:

```
<table>
   <th> head1 </th>
   <th> head2 </th>
   <tr> <td> cell1 </td> <td> cell2 </td> </tr>
   <tr> <td> cell3 </td> <td> cell4 </td> </tr>
</table>
```

By using Jsoup in Java, how to extract the content of row 1 ONLY in that table. The desired output would be like:

```
cell1, cell2
```

I tried this following code but it prints the headings rows which I don't like to:

```
    Element table = doc.getElementsByTag("table").first();
    Elements trs = table.getElementsByTag("tr");
    for (Element tr : trs) {
        for (Element td : tr.getAllElements()) {
            System.out.println("TD: " + td.text());
             ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Elements tdsInSecondRow = doc.select("table tr:eq(1) > td");
for (Element td : tdsInSecondRow)
{
    System.out.println("TD: " + td.text());
}
```

To understand the selector allow me to break it up into 3 sections:

1. table - select the table
2. tr:eq(1) - and from that select the second (0-indexed) tr
3. > td - and from that select the tds which are immediate children of the tr

To make it work using loops, set up a boolean flag or counter to determine when the execution is in the first iteration of the loop, and continue in that circumstance as in:

```
boolean isFirstIteration = true;
for (Element tr : trs) {
    if (isFirstIteration) {
        isFirstIteration = false;
        continue;
    }
    else {
        for (Element td : tr.getAllElements()) { ... }
    }
 }
```

If you use a counter, you could take every 2nd row, or 3rd.

Comment: Instead of a counter, you can use the `:nth-child(an+b)` selector to select every `an+b`th element.  So "every third row starting from the second" is `:nth-child(3n+1)`.